# Suppress swipe events on PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cross-platform, swipe

I'm developing a cross-platform application. I have a couple of swipe gestures for going to next/previous pages. The code looks like this:

```
var myself = this;
jQuery('body').on("swipeleft",function(event){
  console.log('swipeleft');
  if(myself.hasNextPage()){
    myself.nextPage();
  }
});
```

They work well on phone, however, it prevents me from highlighting any text on PC - the swipe event fires in the middle of highlighting! Is there a good way to suppress this event on PC?

Comment: It's more complex that that because many PCs have touch screens where you would want the swipe event to fire. You may want to consider cancelling bubbling during a range select operation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ScottMarcus. I've added an answer to this for anyone else who encounters the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be worked around by checking if there is currently a selection. If there is, then don't fire the function.

```
var myself = this;
jQuery('body').on("swipeleft",function(event){
  console.log('swipeleft');
  if(myself.hasNextPage() && (window.getSelection()+"").length === 0){
    myself.nextPage();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to your own question. Instead add an EDIT section to your original question with additional information.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I wasn't aware of this convention. It's an answer to the question -  I don't see a problem with this.

Comment: It is generally not considered the correct way to go about this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm curious why you think so. This says otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Because you solution may not be correct. You've found a work-around. Your post actually doesn't do what I suggested.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve a problem. Yours was a good suggestion and may work for some, but was not an option for me. In any case, the overhead from firing a swipeleft event and running a single conditional is negligible.

Comment: That's exactly why you should add an edit to your post. To explain what you wound up doing and why you did what you did. Others finding this post may not wind up reading your "complete"  question because it is split into two posts.

Comment: @ScottMarcus this is a legit answer. You can answer your own question. Well done on finding a solution yourself +1.